# Same WooComerce shop for different WP sites?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WooComerce Shop in one of my WP sites. Is there any way to make my other WP sites have this same shop, keeping their own themes? I have no multisite.

If I add one product to the shop of my main site, the rest should be updated.

I use *WC Ajax Product Filter* plugin also.

Update: I have already tried *Multisite*. But seems like it uses subdomains. In my case I have 3 differents wordpress sites that need the same shop.

Comment: I would say yes, but I don't know about any solution which will work out of box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi site will not solve your problem. Cause ***WooCommerce*** takes each site of multi site as a individual site. As far I understood you problem could be solved by using API's and which need a heavy modification. Each site of user will communicate between them through API's. When any of the product will be added or deleted or modified it will send a request to all other sites through API and they will update themselves. But as I said earlier it needs heavy modification.

Comment: I have seen the _woomultistore_ plugin and I thought it could be a solution. Thanks!